# Creating jar by maven to read resources text file from the same jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have simple maven project in Eclipse. The application contains file: src/main/resources/test.txt. I would like to read the file and write it on the output. It works in Eclipse, but not from command line after creating jar file. How to configure the project to work in both ways.
Where am I wrong? 
Not correct jar file, java code, manifest, maven configuration?

Application structure:

[Application structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0UgN.png)

Running:

```
java -jar fileRead-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils
    at fileRead.FileRead.main(FileRead.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

Java code:

```
package fileRead;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class FileRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String file = null;
    try {
        file = IOUtils.toString((new FileRead()).getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.txt"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(file);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.fileRead</groupId>
<artifactId>fileRead</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>fileRead</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>fileRead.FileRead</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

fileRead-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:

```
fileRead
    FileRead.class
META-INF
    maven
    MANIFEST.MF
    test.txt
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: msmorenda
Class-Path: org.apache.commons.io-2.4.jar commons-io-2.4.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.0
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
Main-Class: fileRead.FileRead
```

test.txt:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Comment: why are you compiling the jar and not the java class? I think is that maven have a particular structur, and when you create the jar file there is no directory named "resources"  or "main/java" so I didn't found it

Comment: When you're saying "it works in Eclipse, but not from command line after creating jar file" - do you mean it works in Eclipse but not when you run the JAR file on the server, with Tomcat or something like that?

Comment: I have no server just command line on windows.

Comment: Do you understand what `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `MANIFEST.MF` is pointing to the required dependencies. But the dependencies are not in the same directory as the generated jar file. To copy the required libraries (commons-io) you need to add another plugin to your pom as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>fileread.FileRead</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The `maven-dependency-plugin` with the above configuration will copy the required libraries in the `lib` directory under `target`. Now if you make the `target` directory your current directory and call `java -jar <name_of_jar>` everything should work.

Note: if your want to move your jar file to another location you should package it with the `lib` directory together. And note too, that I changed the package name of your class to `fileread` instead of `fileRead`. Reason? Java convention.

Answer (score -1):

you can create an assembly with maven which includes the libraries you need and then use "mvn package" to create it

pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assemblies/bin-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <tarLongFileMode>gnu</tarLongFileMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

src/assemblies/bin-with-dependencies.xml

```
<assembly>
    <id>bin-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

this creates and archive containing a folder with your jar and all it's libraries
and then run it like

java -cp {directory_jars}/* fileread.FileRead ...

"/*" possibly only works on windows